# Algorithm to find possibilities of word-chains from their nth place in the alphabet using VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, algorithm, collections

I came across a question online which was as follows:

11216812520 is to Alphabet as 183624911413 is to ____________

The first number is simply each letter's number in the alphabet;

1.12.16.8.1.2.5.20 = A.L.P.H.A.B.E.T

When trying to solve another number although not too difficult there are instances where it could be 1 = A, or 11 = K and so on.

I wanted to write an algorithm in VBA which could list every possible combination of words.

My code:

```
Sub routine()

Dim num As String
Dim word As String
Dim arr() As String
Dim c As Collection

Set c = New Collection
c.Add "A", "1"
c.Add "B", "2"
c.Add "C", "3"
c.Add "D", "4"
c.Add "E", "5"
c.Add "F", "6"
c.Add "G", "7"
c.Add "H", "8"
c.Add "I", "9"
c.Add "J", "10"
c.Add "K", "11"
c.Add "L", "12"
c.Add "M", "13"
c.Add "N", "14"
c.Add "O", "15"
c.Add "P", "16"
c.Add "Q", "17"
c.Add "R", "18"
c.Add "S", "19"
c.Add "T", "20"
c.Add "U", "21"
c.Add "V", "22"
c.Add "W", "23"
c.Add "X", "24"
c.Add "Y", "25"
c.Add "Z", "26"

word = ""
num = Cells(1, 5).Value
j = 1

For i = 1 To Len(num)

        If Mid(num, i + 1, 1) = 0 Then

            arr(j) = Mid(num, i, 1) & Mid(num, i + 1, 1)
            j = j + 1

        ElseIf Mid(num, i + 1, 1) <= 6 And Mid(num, i, 1) <= 2 Then

            arr(j) = Mid(num, i, 1)
            arr(j + 1) = arr(j) & Mid(num, i + 1, 1)
            j = j + 1

        Else

            arr(j) = Mid(num, i + 1, 1)

        End If

Next i

Cells(1, 6).Value = word

End Sub
```

I've made a collection of all the letters and their nth place in the alphabet. I'm struggling to get my head round how the words would be generated.

If we look at the second string of numbers in the puzzle above [183624911413], the algorithm could see that 1 and 18 can be letters A and R respectively,
then a new loop would start with the 2nd character for A and see that it's 8 so would be H as 83 is too large, and the 3rd character for R, which would be C as 36 is too large.

As this goes on the algorithm would have to look at the current strings i.e AH and work out their nth place 1,8, see that string is a length of 2 and start again with the 3rd digit in the original number [3].

I can't figure out a good means to do this without a whole bunch of If statements which wouldn't be any good for indeterminable lengths of numbers.

Comment: Seems like an after-construction: **1.12.16.8.1.2.5.20 = A.L.P.H.A.B.E.T**. Why not 11.2.1.6.8.12.5.20 = K.B.A.G ... etc.?

Comment: @peakpeak It could be K.B.A.G... This algorithm would list all the possibilities.

Comment: Ok, maybe I will look into this next week although I'll use C++ and probably recursive

Comment: This just isn't feasible... `11216812520` alone has so many possible outcomes. I'm trying to wrap my head around how I'd do this without several long running loops...

Comment: This problem has been handled several times on line, including at least twice on Stack Overflow.  I'll try to find one of those.

Comment: The problem is a matter of "standard" recursion and dynamic programming.  At each character, you have no more than 2 choices.  If you have none, you report failure and backtrack; if you have only one, you take it and advance (recur); if you have two, you recur on each; the combined results are appended to each prefix found so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue thanks to @AJD who posted the pseudo-code. I've included the code below which will list every possible combination of letters based on a number.

```
Public iRow As Integer

Function ConvertToCharacter(inputString, existingAnswer)
    Dim c As Collection

    Set c = New Collection
    c.Add "A", "1"
    c.Add "B", "2"
    c.Add "C", "3"
    c.Add "D", "4"
    c.Add "E", "5"
    c.Add "F", "6"
    c.Add "G", "7"
    c.Add "H", "8"
    c.Add "I", "9"
    c.Add "J", "10"
    c.Add "K", "11"
    c.Add "L", "12"
    c.Add "M", "13"
    c.Add "N", "14"
    c.Add "O", "15"
    c.Add "P", "16"
    c.Add "Q", "17"
    c.Add "R", "18"
    c.Add "S", "19"
    c.Add "T", "20"
    c.Add "U", "21"
    c.Add "V", "22"
    c.Add "W", "23"
    c.Add "X", "24"
    c.Add "Y", "25"
    c.Add "Z", "26"
    c.Add " ", "27"

    If inputString = "" Then
        Cells(iRow, 1).Value = existingAnswer
        iRow = iRow + 1
        Exit Function
    ElseIf Len(inputString) >= 2 Then
        If Int(Left(inputString, 2)) <= 27 And Int(Left(inputString, 1)) <> "0" Then Call ConvertToCharacter(Right(inputString, Len(inputString) - 2), existingAnswer & c.Item(Left(inputString, 2)))
    End If
    If inputString <> "0" And Left(inputString, 1) <> "0" Then
        Call ConvertToCharacter(Right(inputString, Len(inputString) - 1), existingAnswer & c.Item(Left(inputString, 1)))
    End If


End Function

Sub ListPossibleWords()
Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(20000, 1)).ClearContents
iRow = 5
Call ConvertToCharacter(Cells(2, 2), "")
End Sub
```

Comment: Please give the credits to AJD when you like his answer by confirming hs answer as Answered.

Comment: @Aldert There answer was the most helpful but I've provided the actual solution above. Would it not be more helpful to have the complete answer checked as answered for anyone else seeing this post? I'm happy to give credit. They provided the biggest puzzle pieces but not the completed puzzle.

Comment: Everyone can read all answers so they will conclude youa answer is a worked out version of AJD

Comment: It's easier to conclude from my answer that AJD helped as it states as much at the start of the answer. If I were searching for this question I would want to see the completed answer, then delve more into how I came to that answer if I was really interested to do so. The answer AJD provided only helped with answering part of it.

Comment: And your code is still inefficient, in that you build a standing collection for each recursive call rather than only building it once.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 3):

The easy answer is **recursion**.

- I will assume `c` is a global collection (you do not want to keep
  defining it every time you recurse).
- The input is a string, the output is a string.
- The digits in the string are just symbols, they are not numbers.
- The end point for any recursion line is an empty string (this is easy
  to check)
- I am going greedy first because any single digit will be a valid
  character.

Pseudo-code:

```
Function ConvertToCharacter(inputString, existingAnswer)
    IF inputString is empty THEN 
        output existingAnswer
        END recursion line
    IF length inputString > 2 THEN
        IF first2char are valid char then ConvertToCharacter(inputString less first two char, existingAnswer plus valid char)
    ConvertToCharacter(inputString less first char, existingAnswer plus other valid char)
```

Each single recursion call can branch into two calls. However, if one of the calls results in a nonsensical digit pair (e.g. "83"), it will silently fail (thus not produce a result).

This approach will provide multiple answers for a single string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've been able to write a script which can now do this and output the results to a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

Here the solution in C#, it runs recursive, when the combined digits are <= 26 it creates an extra path.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> Activewords = new List<string>();

        string guessWord = "183624911413";

        AddedWord(Activewords, guessWord, 0, "");
    }

    public static void AddedWord(List<string> Words, string searchWord, int Position, string curWord)
    {
        if (Position == searchWord.Length)
        {
            Words.Add(curWord);
            return;
        }

        char oneChar = searchWord[Position];
        int i = oneChar - 48;

        AddedWord(Words, searchWord, ++Position, curWord + (char)(i + 64));
        if (Position < searchWord.Length)
        {
            int j = i * 10 + searchWord[Position] - 48;

            if (j <= 26) //Alphabet has 26 letters
            {
                AddedWord(Words, searchWord, ++Position, curWord + (char)(j + 64));
            }
        }
         return ;
    }
}
```